# How to use Remodal jQuery plugin with System Js and typescript

Tags: jquery-plugins, systemjs, remodal

I'm having trouble using the jQuery plugin [remodal](http://vodkabears.github.io/remodal/) with [System js](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs).

Remodal is included in the html headers.

The issue I am having is inside the view model class I'm not accessing the remodal.

> Error: Property 'remodal' does not exists on type 'JQuery'

I'm assuming I need to import the plugin into the model somehow, but do not know how to do that.

I have tried 
import * as remodal from '../../../../assets/vendor/remodal/dist/remodal.js';
But get the error cannot find module.

I've also tried to update the system config to include paths, maps, meta data; but I'm kind of confused what is the purpose of the System.config section vs system.import vs the import 'item';